# Failed to grant the 'Log on as a service' right for service account (Error: 1332)

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl

I have a Win32/COM executable written in C++ with ATL. I compiled it from sources in VS2015. It can be registered as a local service with a command like this:

```
myapp.exe /u:uname/p:pass/Service
```

but it is not clear what user name should I specify? And why a local service may require a user?

The source code contains this:

```
class CServiceModule : public CComModule
{
public:
    CServiceModule();
    virtual ~CServiceModule();
    HRESULT RegisterServer(BOOL bRegTypeLib, BOOL bService);
    HRESULT UnregisterServer();
    void Init(_ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* p, HINSTANCE h, UINT nServiceNameID, const GUID* plibid = NULL);
    void Start();
    void ServiceMain(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR* lpszArgv);
    void Handler(DWORD dwOpcode);
    void Run();
    BOOL IsInstalled();
    HRESULT Install();
    BOOL Uninstall();
    LONG Unlock();
    void LogEvent(LPCTSTR pszFormat, ...);
    void SetServiceStatus(DWORD dwState);
    void SetupAsLocalServer();
```

and the executable can also be registered as a local COM server:

```
myapp.exe /RegServer
```

Comment: Every process has an access token (user, groups, privileges), including those that host services. The access token references a logon session. Usually it's for one of the system service accounts: SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE, or NETWORK SERVICE. Any other account has to be logged on as a service by the Services Controller.

Comment: Windows has several types of logons, including Interactive, Network, Batch, and Service. An account has to be granted the right to log on as a Service or Batch, i.e. SeServiceLogonRight and SeBatchLogonRight. A Batch logon is used by the Task Scheduler to run non-interactive tasks in session 0, and a Service logon is used by the Services Controller to run service processes in session 0.